# Deploying ASP.NET Website on Linux Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, linux

Is it possible to develop a website in ASP.NET with C# as the coding Language and MySQL as the database and then deploy the same on Linux server?

I am talking about a full frontal website like forums or discussion board.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).
Please have a look on the [Homepage](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) for further details.

Comment: thanks mate, i came across this thing and had few doubts, so i came here to ask the Pro's. Actually i am building a forum, so need to know if Mono will serve my purpose. Bit skeptic about it, don't want to go ahead and then rollback. Can we develop seemingly applications with it, or there are some restrictions as opposed to the freedom in windows server deployment

Comment: It's relatively simple, you get Mono and MySql, the MySql Mono Connector and work on ASP like you normally would in a windows environment. Mono itself is about as bulky as .NET (maybe smaller) and MySql is very small so deployment is in a way a little easier to a linux box.

Comment: that's my personal opinion: if you are used to work on windows you won't like thelLinux environment that much, because you have to struggle with the configuration and installation on the linux server... it's not so easy like under windows but it works well.

Answer (score 3):

You could always try Mono's implementation of ASP.NET and C#. Personally I've had no issues with it but I haven't tried doing something that complex but from my experience it's pretty close to the standard .NET C#.