# Supportability of a web application (.net c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, operating-system

I got a .net c# web application project and haven't deployed it yet in the server. I am just thinking if the this project will run in any web browser and any operating system? Does the framework of the project will still matters because .net web application runs .net framework? Correct me if I'm wrong.

I just want to ask if I deploy my .net c# web application project can I use it in any operating system? For example is, linux? Will it still support the project? Any help would be appreciate, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask `if the this project will run in any web browser and any operating system?`

My answer is - Web application is meant to run any web browser, because it is meant for web clients i.e. browser, so you should not face any issue for that.
Any operating system - Yes  you can deploye asp.net/C# backed App in linux, for that you need to use `MONO` , answered here - [Deploying ASP.NET Website on Linux Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757511/deploying-asp-net-website-on-linux-server)

And last question - `Does the framework of the project will still matters because .net web application runs .net framework?`

Answer - if you are going to deploy to IIS with app poll having .net v4.0 and developed App is at .net 4.5 , then it will not work, but reverse it true - might need some tweak to config.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy it to IIS the server only need .NET framework but for client is can work for it may work for many browsers you just have to check you fornt-end functionality, e.g. some Ajax methods may not work for IE.

So I recommend to check it any many browsers and make sure your JQuery, Ajax commands work in all browsers.

check this to host in Apache [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715949/attempting-to-host-a-net-web-application-on-apache-mono)